# Display error on google maps in 2 tabs jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem display google maps in tabs,

This is wath i have tried but no sucess, in IE works fine but in Firefox the tab is not showing corect and the line on Route Planner is not work-ing.
Point A to Poin B - there shoud be a line..

Please see this link: http://s1.xfactor-online.com/

Wath i have done rong?

This is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Route Planner</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tabs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.maphilight.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/stil.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var directionDisplay;
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      var map;

function initialize_route() {
      var myOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.662068,23.388755),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_go"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        'map': map,
        'preserveViewport': true,
    });
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions_panel"));
    google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed',
      function() {
        if (currentDirections) {
          oldDirections.push(currentDirections);
          setUndoDisabled(false);
        }
        currentDirections = directionsDisplay.getDirections();
      });
    setUndoDisabled(true);
    calcRoute();
  }

function calcRoute() {
      var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
      var end = document.getElementById("end").value;           
        var request = {
            origin:start,
            destination:end,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          }
        });
      }
      function loadScript_route() {
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize_route";
   document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
   window.onload = loadScript_route;
</script>
<script>
function initialize_map() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.662068,23.388755);
     var myOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_go_full"), myOptions);
     var pos1 = new google.maps.LatLng(42.662068,23.388755);
  var image = 'http://icongal.com/gallery/download/446950/32/png';
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: pos1,
  map: map,
  icon: image
   });  
  marker.setMap(map);
   }

function loadScript_map() {
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize_map";
   document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
   window.onload = loadScript_map;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tabs li").click(function() {
        $("#tabs li").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        $(selected_tab).fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        initialize_route();
        initialize_map();
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="tabs_wrapper">
 <div id="tabs_container">
  <ul id="tabs">
   <li><a href="#tab1" onclick="loadScript_map();">Map</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab2" onclick="loadScript_route();" >Route Planning</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="tabs_content_container">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab_content" style="display: block;">
   <div id="map_go_full"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
   <div id="map">
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td><b>Start position:</b>&nbsp;<br />
       <input type="text" size="35" id="start"  class="poz" name="from" value=""/></td>
      <td><b>Destination:&nbsp;</b>Address (optional), city, country<br />
       <input type="text" size="135" id="end" name="to" class="des" value="Iasi" /></td>
      <td align="right" colspan="2"><br />
       <input class="but" value="Calculate route" type="submit" onclick="calcRoute();" /></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    * Please enter your position to calculate route.
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td class="hs"><b>Satelite Map</b></td>
      <td class="hd"><b>Directions</b></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td valign="top"><div id="map_go"></div></td>
      <td valign="top"><div class="hdir">
        <div id="directions_panel"></div>
       </div>
       <div id="undo"></div></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should be more specific on your problem, and please try to use the speller, you don't need to speak great English but at least be kind enough to auto correct your words.

I didn't find anything different between IE and Firefox, although the console shows up an error in the route planning tag: `Warning: you have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.`

This might be your problem, check your code for repeated includes of google maps and delete them, you only need one per file.

Comment: Hugo please look now , i updated the post with the code of my html.

Comment: The Google Maps API script is loaded 3 times, once in the head, once each in the loadScript_map and loadScripot_route functions.